# How to contain a derived class if I only know base class in C++

Tags: java, c++, inheritance

If I have a base class `Card`. Now I have a class called `DeckOfCard` which contain several cards:

```
class DeckOfCard
{
    private:
         vector<Card> deck;
         //....
}
```

However, here what I really want to do is to have the `DeckOfCard` hold a group of derived class of `Card`, which maybe some specific card type, for instance, poker card.

I know in Java, we can do this:

```
public class DeckOfCard <T extends Card>
{
    private ArrayList<T> deck;
    //...
}
```

How can I do this in C++? Thanks ahead for your advice. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pointer to the parent class, i.e. `Card*`.

```c++
class DeckOfCard
{
    private:
         vector<Card*> deck;
         //....
}
```

Assuming you have a class `PokerCard` that publicly inherits from `Card`, the following statement is valid.

```
PokerCard *pcard = new PokerCard();
deck.push_back(pcard);
```